# Google OR-Tools Error: Evaluating a BoundedLinearExpr as a Boolean value is not supported

Tags: python, error-handling, scheduling, or-tools, deadlines

I want to schedule n jobs on m machines with transition times and alternatives and modified the example in [github/or-tools/scheduling_with_transitions_sat.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/contrib/scheduling_with_transitions_sat.py) because I also want some kind of lateness penalty.

My test input data is with n = 9 and m = 3:

```
jobs_data = [[[(304776, 0, 'r2500', True, 2130458),
   (-1, 1, 'r2500', False, 2130458),
   (-1, 2, 'r2500', False, 2130458)]],
 [[(-1, 0, 'r1200', False, 1295928),
   (193491, 1, 'r1200', True, 1295928),
   (-1, 2, 'r1200', False, 1295928)]],
 [[(215173, 0, 'v3750', False, 1428522),
   (-1, 1, 'v3750', False, 1428522),
   (-1, 2, 'v3750', False, 1428522)]],
 [[(20226, 0, 'v3000', False, 369014),
   (20226, 1, 'v3000', False, 369014),
   (-1, 2, 'v3000', False, 369014)]],
 [[(222962, 0, 'r2500', False, 6517387),
   (222962, 1, 'r2500', False, 6517387),
   (-1, 2, 'r2500', False, 6517387)]],
 [[(-1, 0, 'r1700', False, 1266091),
   (-1, 1, 'r1700', False, 1266091),
   (80988, 2, 'r1700', False, 1266091)]],
 [[(-1, 0, 'r1350', False, 5138051),
   (-1, 1, 'r1350', False, 5138051),
   (89880, 2, 'r1350', False, 5138051)]],
 [[(-1, 0, 'r1200', False, 5699494),
   (131899, 1, 'r1200', False, 5699494),
   (-1, 2, 'r1200', False, 5699494)]],
 [[(-1, 0, 'r1200', False, 505015),
   (-1, 1, 'r1200', False, 505015),
   (126922, 2, 'r1200', True, 505015)]]]
```

with a list of n jobs containing m alternative tasks with `[processing time, machine_id, resource/material, job already active on machine?, deadline/due date]`.

Now I created the variable l_lateness.
lateness_seconds at the moment is the difference between the scheduled end_time and the deadline.

```
l_lateness = model.NewIntVar(-horizon_due_date, horizon_due_date, 'l_lateness')
lateness_seconds = (l_end - job[0][0][4])

model.Add(l_lateness ==  lateness_seconds)

termin.append(l_lateness)
```

I then use the variable in the objective as follows:

```
# Objective.
  makespan = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'makespan')
  model.AddMaxEquality(makespan, job_ends)
  makespan_weight = 1
  transition_weight = 3
  deadline_weight = 5
  print(type(sum(termin)))
  print(type(sum(switch_literals)))
  model.Minimize(makespan * makespan_weight +
                 sum(switch_literals) * transition_weight +
                 sum(termin) * deadline_weight)
```

This works fine.
But I want

```
lateness_seconds = max(0,(l_end - job[0][0][4]))
```

so that only the jobs where the deadline wasn't met count.

If I do this, then I get the following error message and I don't understand why or how to avoid it:

```
NotImplementedError: Evaluating a BoundedLinearExpr as a Boolean value is not supported.
```

I tried to rewrite it as

```
if l_end >= job[0][0][4]:
  model.Add(ueberzogen ==  (l_end - job[0][0][4]))
else:
  model.Add(ueberzogen ==  0)
```

But that gives me the same error for the expression `l_end >= job[0][0][4]`.

I am using `ortools Version: 9.0.9048`.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535624/google-or-tools-notimplementederror-evaluating-a-boundedlinearexpr-as-a-boolean

Comment: I know you can encounter this error when you use something like 
model.Add(lower_bound <= variable <=upper_bound).
And you can avoid it with
model.Add(variable >= lower_bound)
model.Add(variable <=upper_bound).

But I don't understand why 
model.Add(variable1 == max(0, variable2-c) ) triggers the error, but
model.Add(variable1 == (variable2-c) ) don't.

Comment: Isn't "max" the Python function, not one from OR Tools? To use a quantity in the objective you have to construct it as a solver variable, for example using AddMaxEquality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have added pedantic tests in version 9.0 because using min(), max() and other python constructs will not produce a valid model.

Please use AddMinEquality() or AddMaxEquality().